# Turn off auto numbering in OneNote for Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-onenote

Is it possible to turn off auto-numbering in the new OneNote for Windows 10? I have looked through the settings, there's an option to turn off auto-capitalisation, but nothing for this. Searched everywhere and still found no answers.

It's really annoying, because whenever I type '1. ' it automatically creates a numbered list, and there's no way to stop it. It takes a long time to get around it. It is the same for letters and with brackets, eg 'a) '.

Are there any ways to disable this setting? I like the new OneNote, and don't want to use the older 2016 version as it doesn't have some of the new features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to undo the start of the list as soon as it starts it. The icon that pops up also allows you disable auto numbering if you check it's menu.

[image: Image of the menu icon that pops up on starting a list]

Alternatively check your options. The advanced options have a checkbox for automatic numbering and adding of list bullets:

[image: Advanced options]

Comment: Just to clarify, I am using the **new** OneNote app - NOT OneNote 2016. I don't get an icon popping up, or advanced options. Ctrl-Z still works, thanks for the tip - but is there a way to disable the whole thing?